# error ads video [android]

Tags: android, video, ads, crash-reports

I integrated video (with supersonicAds)to my android application but when I try it, my app crash with this message in the logcat :

```html
05-30 16:23:08.581  17153-17153/studio.pomme.m.the33 D/SupersonicWebView﹕ onRVInitSuccess()
05-30 16:23:09.801  17153-17249/studio.pomme.m.the33 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:studio.pomme.m.the33 time:82915288
05-30 16:23:09.991  17153-17153/studio.pomme.m.the33 I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
05-30 16:23:10.001  17153-17153/studio.pomme.m.the33 D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: 0, BMC150 Acceleration Sensor, 200000, 0,
05-30 16:23:10.061  17153-17153/studio.pomme.m.the33 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@43164ac0 time:82915541
05-30 16:23:10.121  17153-17153/studio.pomme.m.the33 A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000034 (code=1), thread 17153 (o.retour.test)
```

My code :

```html
public class Example extends ActionBarActivity implements OnRewardedVideoListener {
    ImageButton a;
    SSAPublisher ssaPub;
    ProgressBar bar;
    private boolean rewardedVideoInitSuccess = false;
    String appKey = "xxx";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
        indice1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a);
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);

        final String userId = "xxx";
        ssaPub = SSAFactory.getPublisherInstance(this);

        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rewardedVideoInitSuccess){
                    ssaPub.showRewardedVideo();
                }else{
                    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ssaPub.initRewardedVideo(appKey, userId, null, Example.this);
                }


            }
        });
}

    @Override
    public void onRVInitSuccess(AdUnitsReady adUnitsReady) {
        rewardedVideoInitSuccess = true;
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRVInitFail(String s) {
        rewardedVideoInitSuccess = false;
       bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRVNoMoreOffers() {
        rewardedVideoInitSuccess = false;
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRVAdCredited(int i) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onRVAdClosed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRVGeneric(String s, String s2) {

    }
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        if (ssaPub != null) {

            ssaPub.onResume (this);

        }

    }

    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if (ssaPub != null) {

            ssaPub.onPause(this);

        }

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        if (ssaPub != null) {

            ssaPub.release(this);

        }

    }





}
```

I think it's a memory problem but I'm not sure... Maybe will know you explain me what it is and what I have to do.